# Angular: count class instances, display on page

Tags: angular, angular-lifecycle-hooks

Big noob, first question. Course project "quiz app" displays question after question, and results at the end. I want to add a count of correct answers, by counting the number of elements with class "correct" on the results page. Please let me know if any more information is needed or anything!

Tried so far:

-test1: "counts" them and displays just fine, problem is there are 0 when it performs the count, because they're not created yet.

-test2: counts them after they're created using lifecycle hook ngAfterViewChecked(). Console.log displays correct number; but I don't know how to transfer this instead to the template. Declared a variable within the component, had the lifecycle hook's function change the variable, and included the variable on the template; but it just doesn't appear on the page the way test1() does.

results.component.html:

```
<div class="results">
  <mat-card>
    <mat-card-title>
      <h1><u>Results</u></h1>
    </mat-card-title>
    <br/>
    <div
      *ngFor="let a of answers.values"
      class="answer"
      [ngClass]="{ correct: a.correct }"
    >
      {{a.value}}
      <br/>
      <br/>
    </div>
    <button routerLink="/">Home</button>
  </mat-card>
  {{test1()}}
  {{test2}}
</div>
```

results.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AsyncValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';
import { Answers } from '../quiz.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-results',
  templateUrl: './results.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./results.component.scss']
})
export class ResultsComponent {
  @Input() answers: Answers;
  
  test1() {
    return document.querySelectorAll(".correct").length;
  }

  public test2: number;

  ngAfterViewChecked(){
    console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".correct").length);
    this.test2 = document.querySelectorAll(".correct").length;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why dont you return `answers.filter(answer=> answer.correct).length;` in `test1()` method?

Comment: @NimittShah VSCode red underlines "filter" with the following message:

Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'typeof Answers'.ts(2339)

Comment: You can not use filters on type (`Answers`). Use filter on variable `answers`.

Comment: @NimittShah instructor said to skip, but thanks for your help!